# Disable Transparent Hugepages on all nodes?

Tags: linux, centos, mongodb

I upgraded our mongo infrastructure from 2.6 to 3.0 (on way to 3.4) and when I logged into a secondary via local mongo client I saw a warning about transparent hugepages. After some research I decided to implement their suggestion.

I am going to puppetize the init.d script mongo suggests to disable THP on mongo servers, but then I got to thinking, should I disable it for all nodes? Is there any degradation from disabling THP on other nodes (nginx, nfs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [RedHat THP documention](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/s-memory-transhuge.html) recommends enabling THP on most systems:

> THP hides much of the complexity in using huge pages from system administrators and developers. As the goal of THP is improving performance, its developers (both from the community and Red Hat) have tested and optimized THP across a wide range of systems, configurations, applications, and workloads. This allows the default settings of THP to improve the performance of most system configurations. However, THP is not recommended for database workloads.

So disabling `THP`on all nodes won't improve performance.

Comment: Thx. I'll go with this.